# Discord.PY ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: discord.py

I'm new here.
I recently bought a udemy course to learn discord.py and have been facing this issue when install discord.py
guys any idea what's wrong? I'm installing Discord.py on my pycharm and this is happening. http://image.aspirehosting.in/u/5hsMFG.png

py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]

Answer (score 1):

`aiohttp` has not been compiled for Python 3.12, but was compiled [for versions between 3.6 to 3.11](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/#files) - that means its source code gets downloaded and compiled on your computer, and you may be experiencing the reason they don't pre-build for Python 3.12

You should use (at the most) Python 3.11 if you want to have `aiohttp` working.